# Git push remove file uploaded in my server -laravel

Tags: php, laravel, git

I develop a laravel website this the path where i upload my files

```
$path = $request->file('picture')->move(base_path().'/public/profilepic', $fileNameToStore);
```

I add this file in .gitignore

> public/profilepic
>
> /public/profilepic

and when i push the files that was uploaded enligne in my server they removed and overrided by the local directory

that how i push

```
git add .

git commit -m "make it better"

git push heroku master
```

Comment: I think you have to decide first what file you need to ignore in `.ignore` file otherwise git will make changes whatever you will push.

Comment: i ignore this folder /public/profilepic

Comment: was this in `git status` ?

Comment: no ? i don't understand really what you say?

Comment: what you do `git status` is it displaying still in git list or not ?

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Please add your .gitignore file content!